# Azure Data Factory add logical operators with JSONPath expression values in dynamic content field

Tags: json, azure, rest, azure-data-factory

to realize pagination in my pipeline where I execute a REST GET Request I need to pass the next_offset value from the output to the PaginationRules.

I can do this by typing $.next_offset to the dynamic content field but I get an error when the pagination is finished and returns -1 as next_offset value.

Unfortunately I get an exception when the value is lower then zero. Instead it only succeed when the HTTP status code is 204 (No Content), or any of the JSONPath expressions in "paginationRules" returns null.

Because of that I wanted to add an If condition to the dynamic content field which looks like this now:

```
@if(equals('$.next_offset','-1'),'$.next_offset',null)
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to use the JSON path expression like this inside of a logical function I guess.

I would be glad if you can tell me how a JSON Path expression needs to be entered in logical functions.

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to use the JSON path expression like this inside of a logical function. I think you need to change to return value of `next_offset` in your application.